# "Ramp up" phase for periodic function

Tags: functions, mathematical-modeling, periodic-functions

I have a periodic function describing the angle of an impeller blade rotating around an axis (2 pi is a full rotation):

[image]

(R code:)

```
param.rps = 2     # rotations per second

getAngle <- function(t) { t %% param.rps / param.rps * pi * 2.0 }

x = seq(0, 10, 0.1)
y = getAngle(x)
plot(y ~ x, xlab="Time [seconds]", ylab="Angle", axes=F, ylim=c(0,2)*pi)
axis(side=1)
axis(side=2, at=pi*0:2,labels=c("0", "pi", "2*pi"),las=2)
```

Now I would like to add a "ramp up" phase where the impeller accelerates from 0 up to its final rps. I tried just adding a factor to the formula that linearly increases up to 1, and that does achieve the acceleration but has the unwanted side effect of making the impeller "jump" back halfway through its rotation:

```
param.rampup = 5  # how many seconds is the ramp up phase
getAngle <- function(t) { pmin(1.0, (t / param.rampup)) * t %% param.rps / param.rps * pi * 2.0 }
```

[image]

I assume the cycle points would have to be shifted to the right by the amount of the ramp up phase somehow but I've been playing around a bit and can't make it produce the behaviour I want. Does anybody have any hints?

Comment: I don't really understand the R code, but I think you have defined getAngle() in a non-intuitive way. The way that I would limit the angle between 0 and $2\pi$ is to put the expression in $\mod 2\pi$. As I interpret it, you have not done it that way. Notice also that if you have a slower ramp up time, the "straight" lines should be moved slightly to the right. So for example, without ramp up you have $\theta=0$ at $t=6~\text{s}$, but with rampup time you should have $\theta > 0 $ at  $t=6~\text{s}$. (The angle is $\theta$ here). Do you see what I mean?

Comment: @MattiP. Partially: The second part of moving the straight lines to the right was what I tried to express with my "cycle points should be shifted to the right", I think that's exactly the root of the problem, I just haven't found a way to solve it yet. Everything I tried produced weird results... Regarding the formula: You can just copy the block into https://rdrr.io/snippets/ and play with it if you like, the reason rps is in there in the first place is because I need something to control the impeller speed (i.e. slope of the lines). (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) So what I'm trying to do is calculate a number between 0 and 1 describing the degree of rotation (t % rps / rps ) and then multiplying it by 2 pi because I need my function output to be in radian units. What expression would you use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
param.rps = 2     # rotations per second
param.rampup = 5  # how many seconds is the ramp up phase

getAngle <- function(t) {
  ifelse(t < param.rampup,
         ((1/(2*param.rampup*param.rps) * t^2)*2*pi) %% (2*pi),
         ((1/(2*param.rps) * param.rampup + (t-param.rampup) / param.rps)*2*pi) %% (2*pi)
         )
}
x = seq(0, 10, 0.05)
y = getAngle(x)
plot(y ~ x, xlab="Time [seconds]", ylab="Angle", axes=F, ylim=c(0,2)*pi)
axis(side=1)
axis(side=2, at=pi*0:2,labels=c("0", "pi", "2*pi"),las=2)
```

[image]